# Why does the loop skip the if statement

Tags: python

I was trying to make a password system but whenever I run my code it ignores the if statement,
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
key = 1057

while True:

    inputKey = input("Enter your password ")

    if inputKey == key:
        print("Welcome Back!")
        break

    else:
        print("Incorrect password, Please try again.")
```

Comment: `input` returns a string and you're comparing that against an `int`

Comment: To put it another way, `1057` is not the same as `"1057"`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that, aren't you supposed to put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compared the integer 1057 to a string. Put it into quotes and it will work or you can also do `inputKey = int(input("Enter your password "))`

```
key = "1057"

while True:

    inputKey = input("Enter your password ")

    if inputKey == key:
        print("Access granted")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect password, Please try again.")
```

Output: Access granted

Comment: Those are quotes, not parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. I mean quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your input to `int(input("Enter your password "))`. Because, in python, input is taken as string by default. So "1057" is not equal to 1057. That's the reason your if condition is getting skipped. Your corrected code:

```
key = 1057

while True:
    try:
        inputKey =int(input("Enter your password "))
        if inputKey == key:
            print("Welcome Back!")
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect password, Please try again")
    except ValueError:
        print("Password must be integer")
```

Comment: A side effect of doing it this way (rather than making `key` a string) is that you'll raise a `ValueError` on any password attempt that can't be converted to an `int`.  This may not be desirable.

Comment: Yeah I know, there might be value error but according to my guesses OP is a beginner, so I don't think they know try and except statements. But still, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I do know try and except statements but I went with making key a string bc it is simpler.

Comment: I knew it. I've replied to @Samwise that you might be a beginner and have no idea about try and except statements. I don't know why but it didn't click me to convert the key to string but while editing I noticed that somebody had already answered the idea so I skipped it and used try and except concept